# How to use ActiveRecord's serialize with array of hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, activerecord, simple-form

In my model Post.rb I have `serialize :facts` call.
What I try to accomplish is that users can save their own key/value pairs to the `facts` column. When user opens /posts/new page, I want there to be three empty key-value inputs. User can then fill in values like:

```
[color                ]: [very blue     ]
[length of the street ]: [not that long ]
[etcetera             ]: [etcetera      ]
```

To build the form I'm using Simple Form gem and tried already to use

```
= f.simple_fields_for :facts do |ff|
  = f.input :key
  = f.input :value
```

It generates only one key/value and saves it very good in YAML format in 'facts'-field! However when I try to add an array it doesn't work. It saves only the last key/value pair.

Well, I know what problem is, but not how to solve it.

I need something that would generate input fields with values like: `post[facts][][key]` and `post[facts][][value]`. Right now it only generates three of `post[facts][key]` `post[facts][value]` inputs.

Comment: Did you solved this problem?

Comment: @RuanCarlos Probably I solved it, but I can't really remember how. It's already three years ago :) You could try to write a custom serialiser in the model. This serialiser could do things like parse all 'key' fields to hash keys and all 'value' fields to hash values corresponding to the keys.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I created manually the form.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to merge an empty pair with existing elements in the collection?